# CAML get child folders count

Tags: caml-query

I want to query all folders from a document library and I am using following query

```
<Where>
<Eq>
    <FieldRef Name="ContentType" />
    <Value Type="Text">Folder</Value>
</Eq>
</Where>
```

I get 2 root folders, folder 1 has a child folder and 2 files and folder 2 has no folder but 1 file, Can I get the number of child folders and files with each folder with a CAML query? for example folder 1 should give me 3 and folder 2 should give me 1 and if there is no child file or folder it should give me 0.

Answer (score 1):

Written a console for you. You can use it as per your need

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://spserver:1111/"))
        {
            using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
            {
                SPList lib = web.Lists.TryGetList("TestLibrary");

                SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
                query.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='ContentType' /><Value Type='Text'>Folder</Value></Eq></Where>";
                SPListItemCollection coll = lib.GetItems(query);
                if (coll != null && coll.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (SPListItem item in coll)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Parent Folder : " + item.Folder.Name);
                        getChildFolder(web, item);

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    static void getChildFolder(SPWeb web, SPListItem item)
    {
        SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
        query.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='ContentType' /><Value Type='Text'>Folder</Value></Eq></Where>";
        query.Folder = item.Folder;
        SPListItemCollection coll = item.ParentList.GetItems(query);
        if (coll != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\tChild Folder : " + coll.Count);
            //foreach (SPListItem folderItem in coll)
            //{
            //    Console.WriteLine("\tChild Folder : " + folderItem.Folder.Name);
            //}
        }
    }
```

This will give you count for each parent folder.

**Folder Structure in my library:**

[image: My Library]

**Output:**

[image: Output]

Answer (score 1):

```
<View Scope="RecursiveAll">
<ViewFields>
    <FieldRef Name="FileLeafRef" />
    <FieldRef Name="FileDirRef" />
    <FieldRef Name="ItemChildCount" />
</ViewFields>
<Query>
    <Where>
        <Eq>
            <FieldRef Name="FileDirRef" />
            <Value Type="Text">/sites/devsite/Shared Documents</Value>
        </Eq>
    </Where>
</Query>
</View>
```

[image]

```
<FieldRef Name="ItemChildCount" /> is what I was looking for.
```